# SQL query about database

Tags: sql, database

I have some trouble with SQL.
I have database structure like below
[image]
I should write a query that return: All moviestar's name and address, where they are woman(G='F') and address="Berlin" + all studio's name and address, where address="Berlin" too. Ordered by address.

My suggestion is:

```
SELECT * FROM
   (SELECT name, address 
   FROM MovieStar 
   WHERE gender = 'F'
   UNION 
   SELECT name, address FROM Studio) T 
WHERE T.address LIKE '%Berlin%' ORDER BY T.address;
```

Comment: Help us help you - share some sample data and the result you're trying to get

Comment: I took a look at the DB structure and if you really are using the names as the keys you have a big problem. Use for example and integer id for each table and the link the tables using the id's, not the names.

Comment: You should use numeric keys. What if there are two films with the same name or two stars with the same name?

Comment: I am not the creator of the database and its structure, but i agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.

```
SELECT name, address 
   FROM MovieStar 
   WHERE gender = 'F' AND address LIKE '%Berlin%'
   UNION 
   SELECT name, address FROM Studio WHERE address LIKE '%Berlin%' 
ORDER BY address;
```

Comment: It looks like close to my solution, tnx.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this

```
SELECT name, address from MovieStar WHERE gender='F' AND address LIKE '%Berlin%'
UNION 
SELECT name, address from Studio WHERE address LIKE '%Berlin'
```

and if you want use subquery like you do in your example, I think you have to add "as" keyword for sub query

```
SELECT * FROM
   (SELECT name, address 
   FROM MovieStar 
   WHERE gender = 'F'
   UNION 
   SELECT name, address FROM Studio) AS T 
WHERE T.address LIKE '%Berlin%' ORDER BY T.address;
```

but I'm not sure, that's a good deal for performance since you will have a memory table created and then projected

Comment: Performance is not a problem. I just want to be sure that my solution will work, because i can't test it.